# I need help renaming android package

Tags: android

Is there a good way to rename a package name. I began by naming my project com.thetech.simple and I want to name it com.curcoelectronics.hunting. Do I have to start over and import my files to a new project or can I just change the name in my manifest and java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

right click on project -> Android Tools -> Rename Application Package